# linux: execute thread after every one second

Tags: linux, sockets, pthreads

I am working with threads  i have implemented two thread one to receive packets and another for sending the packets. i want to implement one new thread in background that runs after every one second and maintain the counter for no of packet received and send.

Comment: You had better learn how to use non-blocking sockets and one thread. Start here: http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html#strategies

Comment: I don't understand?  Why can the receive/send threads not maintain the counts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one possible solution:

```
// globally accesible variables - can be defined as extern if needed
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int synchronized_received = 0;
int synchronized_sent = 0;

// third threads' main function
void *third_thread_main(void *args){
  while(1){
    struct timespec time;
    time.tv_sec = 1;
    time.tv_nsec = 0;
    nanosleep(&time, NULL);
    int received, sent;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    received = synchronized_received;
    sent = synchronized_sent;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    fprintf(stdout, "Received %d, Sent %d\n", received, sent);
  }
  return NULL;
}

// in receiving thread put this after received packet
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
synchronized_received++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

// in sending thread put this after packet sent
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
synchronized_sent++;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```